# How to set 2 different urls for opencpu?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, opencpu

I want to set 2 different urls for OpenCpu. Is it possible?

```
ocpu.seturl("https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/igraph/R");


ocpu.seturl("https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/customlibrary/R");
```

Answer (score 1):

No, each OpenCPU app calls out to a single API package endpoint. There can be no ambiguity about which function gets called.

If you are building an app `customlibrary` but also want to call functions from `igraph` you can import + export these `igraph` functions in your `customlibrary` package `NAMESPACE` file.

You can also write wrapper functions in `customlibrary` that call out to `igraph` functions. Either way make sure to `imports: igraph` in the `DESCRIPTION` file in `customlibrary`.